# Unable to delete Cloud TPU

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

I have a TPU node name 'demo-tpu' which I am try to delete, using the command `gcloud beta compute tpus delete demo-tpu`

This results in the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.tpus.delete) ABORTED: The resource is already in the process of being deleted
```

However, when I use the command `gcloud beta compute tpus describe demo-tpu`, it says the TPU is restarting.

I also tried using the delete option in the GCP console, but it does not seem to work as well. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Update: The node did get deleted, but after ~40 minutes, as opposed to the usual 2 minutes. Still no clue as to what caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud team has since introduced the *ctpu* tool. It wraps the bringup and deletion ops with *ctpu up* and *ctpu delete*. But as you probably have already observed, it takes time to bring up TPU for the first time and delete the VM and/or TPU.

You may also want to double check the "VM instances" and "TPU" tabs in the GCE console to make sure the resources have indeed been deleted.

FYI, you can install *ctpu* locally which so far works pretty well.